# flash as3 passing string with special characters (like newlines `\n`) from JS to flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I've encountered with followng:

for example we have html

```
<div id="123">123\n456</div>
```

when I take div's contents as innerHTML

```
var a = document.getElementById('123').innerHTML
```

and pass it to a flash object

```
top.flashObj.FlashFunction(a);
```

then it treats it not as `123\n456` but

```
123
456
```

I mean that `a` var comes in flash with REAL newline character.

What should I do to avoid such things as passing vars with special chars JS>SWF and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll usually do \\n instead and then run a regex replace on it:

```
myString.replace( /\\\n/g, "\n" );
```

Comment: thats not the problem I've described. there's real `123\n456` (`backslash` and `n` chars) in div contents and it is passed into swf as `newline` (one char instead of two chars)

Comment: ok so let me make sure I'm getting this, `a` value in the parameter is `123\n456` but in the flash end is there is no `\n` in the string parameter correct?

Comment: yes. your suggestion is right. I already tried as you said - have sent to swf `a.replace(/\\/,'\\\\');` but there's such thing as `\'` (literally backsash and single quote) in `a` string and flash sends it back as `\\'` (two backslashes and one quote).

Comment: the only guess I have is to replace all \ as `bAckSlaSh` when js>swf and `bAckSlaSh` as \ when back from swf to js

Comment: Honestly anyway you decide to do it the best way is to format into something to be replaced. There isn't a real good workaround for it otherwise.